# jquery htmldecode

Tags: jquery

how will i decode the string in the following line

```
  $("#" + result["DivName"]).append(result["SavedValue"]);
```

ok i am using this scenario to save myself from the script attack. ok the thing is that if some one rights alert('hi') in the ckeditor . it saves in the database as it is but when i retrieves it i first encode it and then display it. but the thing is that encoded version is not displaying in the div which have a edit button by pressing it a ckeditor will open with the text in the div , yes i am using json.

the bottom line is that the scripts should not execute

Comment: I think after your edit the question's very unclear, you want to strip *just* scripts and leave all other HTML formatting? It sounds like you're after a XSS library, rather than an encode/decode solution. And in that case, which server-side platform are you using?

Comment: the thing is that i am really having a encode and decode problem ,displaying the data in divs,i am not using anything else . what will be ur sol for this

Comment: i don't want to strip script , just don' t let it to execute

Comment: @mazhar - The only way that happens, is to strip it out :) Is there other formatting in there, or it's just plain text?

Comment: i realize that it is not possible to have both html displays as it is and script not executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert it as HTML instead use [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) like this:

```
$("#" + result["DivName"]).append(decodeURIComponent(result["SavedValue"]));
```

Depending on how you're getting the data though, you may want a different approach...based on your syntax I'm not sure if you're dealing with JSON or something else...and if so how it's encoded.

If you are going though a JSON result, it should only be *escaped* coming back from the server if you intend to use it as HTML, in which case you wouldn't need to decode it on the client at all, just parsing it as JSON would give you the HTML string.